# OAuth2 Authentication Redirection error in PHP

Tags: support, authentication, oauth2, php

I'm trying to authenticate into Stack Exchange's API with the following URL:

```
https://stackexchange.com/oauth/dialog?client_id=3535&scope=write_access&redirect_uri=https://stackexchange.com/oauth/login_success
```

This returns a redirect with access_token into queryString:

[image: OAuth response]

The problem comes when I try to get the redirection with Curl: it return 500 internal server error.

## EDIT

My idea is instantiate an OAuth2 class like this:

```
$oauth2 = new OAuth2('key', 'client_id', 'scope', 'redirect_uri'); 
$accessToken = $oauth2->getAccessToken();

// For auth require methods
$client = new Client('key', $accessToken);

// Without auth
$client = new Client();
```

I don't want to obtain the **access_token** manually pasting the URL in the browser. I want to generate the token with this four values.

**So, any suggestion on how to implement the** `getAccessToken()` **method?**

Comment: Been a while since I tried this in PHP.  I don't think you need cURL or to actually redirect.  Just grab the response URL.  It has the `access_token` and that's all you need from this step of the auth process.

Comment: @BrockAdams I just edit the question, can you explain your approach with an example, please?

Comment: Why are you redirecting to `stackexchange.com/oauth/login_success`?  Redirect to a page on your server.  Or just [do a self redirect](http://stackphp.quickmediasolutions.com/examples/view_source.php?file=auth_implicit.php) and read the URL parameters on redirect.

Comment: Sorry @BrockAdams but I'm quite missing. What is the `redirected_uri` when I use via terminal and in the localhost?

Comment: @BrockAdams Can you rewrite my above URL to work as Self Redirect, please?